# Flutter : How insert dynamic list to sqflite

Tags: flutter, initialization, sqflite, dynamic-list

I have an app in flutter want to add list of data to sqlite database at initializing the database ,I have problem with the type of model.
I have this model for data :

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Clubs> clubsFromMap(String str) =>
    List<Clubs>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Clubs.fromMap(x)));

String clubsToMap(List<Clubs> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Clubs {
  Clubs({
    this.id,
    this.club,
    this.leagueId,
    this.price,
    this.surname,
    this.leagueName,
    this.counter,
    this.selected,
  });

  int id;
  String club;
  int leagueId;
  String price;
  String surname;
  String leagueName;
  int counter;
  String selected;

  factory Clubs.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Clubs(
        id: json["id"],
        club: json["club"],
        leagueId: json["league_id"],
        price: json["price"],
        surname: json["surname"],
        leagueName: json["league_name"],
        counter: json["counter"],
        selected: json["selected"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "club": club,
        "league_id": leagueId,
        "price": price,
        "surname": surname,
        "league_name": leagueName,
        "counter": counter,
        "selected": selected,
      };
}
```

and I have this list of data for that model :

```
var clubs = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "club": "Manchester City",
      "league_id": 1,
      "price": "10.00",
      "surname": "MCY",
      "league_name": "Premier League",
      "counter": 1,
      "selected": "No"
    },
  ..................etc
]
```

no I want tho add this initial data to sqflite database ,I created thsi :

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
class DataBaseService {
  static final DataBaseService _instance = DataBaseService.internal();
  factory DataBaseService() => _instance;
  DataBaseService.internal();

  Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await intializeDataBase();
      return _database;
    }
  }

Future<Database> intializeDataBase() async {
    var dir = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = dir + "clubs.db";
    var database =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (db, version) {
      db.execute('''
      create table $clubsTableName(
        columnId integer primary key,
        $columnClub text not null,
        $columnLeaueId integer,
        $columnPrice double,
        $columnSurname text not null,
        $columnLeagueName text,
        $columnCounter integer.
        $columnSelected text,
      )
      ''');
db.insert(clubsTableName,clubs.toMap());
```

it say that toMap() isn't defined ,if I changed it to clubsFromMap(clubs) instead of clubs.toMap() it says : `The argument type 'List<Clubs>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Object>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after change the list format like this:

```
var clubs = {"data":{
    {
      "id": 1,
      "club": "Manchester City",
      "league_id": 1,
      "price": "10.00",
      "surname": "MCY",
      "league_name": "Premier League",
      "counter": 1,
      "selected": "No"
    },
  ..................etc}
}
```